# Setting up alerts for metrics in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I'm sending data to Splunk and everything is working just fine, i can see the data that i'm sending and run a query and get results. Right now I'm only using a test data set, but eventually people will be sending their own fields (as well as the mandatory ones). My question is, since I don't know what kind of data they will be sending, can I still set up alerts for them? Can I create something general?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard to create a generic alert that's actually useful.  You may be able to craft something using the mandatory fields, but it may not be all that helpful.

If you're opposed to letting users create their own alerts then let them come to you with what they want.